# Breeze memory use

Tags: breeze

I develop the SPA using Breeze, ASP.NET Web API and MySQL database. The main entity of database (Code First EF) have 4 one-to-many relations and 20 simple properties. When I've downloaded ~ 500 this entities (the total quantitity of objects with related entities ~ 2000), the Chrome tab process use 250+ Mb of RAM (without loading UI). And this value grown if I save some entitites. Is it normal? How can I reduce this value?

Answer (score 2):

As of breeze v 1.1 we did fix some memory leaks in breeze and reduced some of the memory pressure while processing large queries.  In addition, the latest version of the Q library, which breeze uses has also fixed some leaks.  Hopefully, you should see a smaller footprint now. Please post any further findings.... and thanks for commenting on this.

Answer (score 1):

So far I have been unable to repro this result, so can I get a little more information? Just to make sure that I am clear, your query is for 500 root entities, each with 20 simple properties, and 4 navigation properties and the total number of entities queried is only 2000 ( so each navigation property has on average on 1 related entity? (2000/(500*4)).

What are the sizes of the related entities?

Are you using 'EntityQuery.expand' to retrieve the relation properties or are you using 'entityAspect.loadNavigationProperty'?

Each breeze entityManager stores a single copy of each entity by key, so memory use should not expand unless you are retrieving more entities ( or using more than one entityManager.).

Comment: I was a little wrong in description of my model, sorry. The root entitiy have six 1-to-many properties. But in 5 of them max quantity of related entities doesn't exceed 5. The 6th relation has the folowing scheme of 1-to-many relations: 1 Root Entity -> 1st Navigation Entity (14 simple and 8 1-to-1 properties, max quantity is unlimited, ~ 10 by this moment) -> 2nd Navigation Entity (11 simple and one 1-to-1 properties, max quantity ~ 5) -> 3rd Navigation Entity (20 simple and 3 1-to-1 properties, max quantity ~ 50). The "->" symbol indicates 1-to-many relation.

Comment: I use one entityManager and 'EntityQuery.expand' expression.

Comment: So how many entities in total are you bringing down? and how many properties ( on average ) for each entity type. Ideally you could give me an estimate of the total memory that you 'expect' the entities that you are retrieving to take; assuming that each unique entity is only counted once.

Comment: The total quantity of entities is ~5000 with 15 simple properties (on average) for each by this moment. I think that 250-300 Mb per 50000 such uniq entities would be an ideal (or at least per 25k =).